# If $\alpha$ is a root of a simple lie algebra, prove that $\langle \alpha,\alpha \rangle \neq 0$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

If $\alpha$ is a root of a simple lie algebra, prove that $\langle \alpha,\alpha \rangle$ not equal to $0$. From this, I want to prove that the $\langle,\rangle$ could be used as a scalar product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t$ be the Lie algebra of a maximal torus of a compact form.  Then $\alpha \in (it)^*$ so that $i\alpha \in t^*$.  But the Killing form is definite on $t^*$ so that $\langle \alpha,\alpha \rangle = - \langle i \alpha, i\alpha\rangle \ne 0$.

I'm not sure what you mean by trying to prove that $\langle,\rangle$ can be used as a scalar product-- it is a scalar product!

Comment: we define <α, β> ≡ (hα , hβ ) where ρ(k) = (hρ , k) where ρ is root. I wanted to prove that <,> satisfies the properties of a scalar product i.e. <α,α> is positive definite.

Comment: It is because the Killing form is negative definite on $t^*$ and therefore will be positive definite on $it^*$.